# Contact gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I followed [this blog](http://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/03/07/contacts-ruby-gem-import-contacts-from-gmail-yahoo-hotmail/#comment-1671). I found one error: I mentioned in environment.rb require ‘contacts’.

When I use this `require ‘contacts’` the server never started. When I replace this `require ‘contacts’` the server starting but some syntax errors came in URL. How can I import my contacts?

Comment: Since you are using Rails (I assume since you mentioned environment.rb) why not put the gem requirement in the Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

That blog entry predates Rails 3, and thus does not refer to the fact that you must add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'contacts'
```

and then run `bundle install`. As a result of this you do *not* need to put `require 'contacts'` anywhere, as Bundler will require it for you.

Comment: +1  Rails-2 you put it in environment.rb, but in rails 3 (or rails 2 w/bundler) you follow Andrew's procedure.